# Yii2 GridView multiple filters in one column (<, >, = )

Tags: filter, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to filter a numeric value by values ​​greater, lesser or equal to the one given in input.

So far I have managed to filter individually or at most by >= or <=

```
 ->andFilterWhere(['<=', 'production_order.qnt', $this->qnt])
```

but I can't find a solution to filter by writing in the input "<500"
or "> 500" because in the rules I set this value ( qnt ) as integer.

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['product_routing_id', 'qnt', 'qnt_worked', 'production_status_id', 'production_order_id', 'acceptance_order_id', 'customer_id', 'product_id', 'casting_id', 'trash'], 'integer'],
}
```

Do i need a custom filter for it?
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to create your condition in code as `x < 500 or x > 500` or do you want to allow user to enter the condition like that in filter? Btw `x < 500 or x > 500` is exactly same as `x != 500`.

Comment: i want to allow the user the enter conditions like <500 in the filter input.

Comment: I have added a comprehensive function which I use below. However, if you want to keep it simple: (1) You need to change the rule to string. "<100" is a string, not an integer (2) If you want to keep $qnt an integer because it is in your model for validation, you can simply create a new variable public $qntFilter in the dataprovider and set the rule to string. Then in the gridview you use the attribute qntFilter. The filter variable is only used in the dataprovider and does not impact the validation of the model

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have created for this (and yes, you need to change the rule to string because "<" is not an integer, it is a string)

First I have a public static function which is contained in a class called NumberFilter. NumberFilter contains one public function getArray()

This allows the user to apply any of the following filters (obviously it allows greater than as well)

1. < 1000
2. <= 1000
3. = 1000
4. < 1k
5. < 1,000
6. 1000
7. Null
8. !null

{

```
    public static function getArray($param, $filterString)
    {
        if (empty($filterString)){
            return [];
        }

        // remove any whitespace
        $filterString = trim($filterString);
        $filterString = str_replace(" ", "", $filterString);
        $filterString = str_replace(",", ".", $filterString);
        $filterString = strtolower($filterString);

        if (substr($filterString, 0, 2) == ">=") {
            $n = substr($filterString, 2);
            $n = self::applyMultiplier($n);
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return [">=", $param, (integer)$n];
        } else if (substr($filterString, 0, 1) == ">") {
            $n = substr($filterString, 1);
            $n = self::applyMultiplier($n);
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return [">", $param, (integer)$n];
        } else if (substr($filterString, 0, 2) == "<=") {
            $n = substr($filterString, 2);
            $n = self::applyMultiplier($n);
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return ["<=", $param, (integer)$n];
        } else if (substr($filterString, 0, 1) == "<") {
            $n = substr($filterString, 1);
            $n = self::applyMultiplier($n);
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return ["<", $param, (integer)$n];
        } else if (substr($filterString, 0, 1) == "=") {
            $n = substr($filterString, 1);
            $n = self::applyMultiplier($n);
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return [$param => (integer)$n];

        } else if ($filterString == "null") {
            return [$param => NULL];

        } else if ($filterString == "!null") {
            return ['NOT', [$param => NULL]];

        } else if (is_numeric($filterString)) {
            return [$param => (integer)$filterString];
        }
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'The filter was not a valid number. Please try again');
        return '0=1'; // invalid query - return no results
    }


    // used to replace k with 1,000 etc
    private static function applyMultiplier($n)
    {
        if (strpos($n, "k") !== false) {
            $n = str_replace("k", "", $n);
            $n = doubleval($n) * 1000;
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return $n;
        }

        if (strpos($n, "m") !== false) {
            $n = str_replace("m", "", $n);
            $n = doubleval($n) * 1000000;
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return $n;
        }

        if (strpos($n, "b") !== false) {
            $n = str_replace("b", "", $n);
            $n = doubleval($n) * 1000000000;
            if (is_numeric($n))
                return $n;
        }

        // nothing to do
        return $n;

    }


}
```

From within the DataProvider, I can call the filter as follows:

```
$query->andWhere(NumberFilter::getArray('FIELD_NAME', $this->FIELD_NAME));
```

This function will return the array needed by Yii, for example:

```
['>' , 'FIELD_NAME' , 1000]
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use between

```
andFilterWhere(['between', 'created_at', $start_date, $end_date])
```